# Simple voltage build-up circuit

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell, energy-harvesting, raspberry-pi

I'm planning on buying a Raspberry Pi  and I want to power it using solar energy. Since the voltage input needed by the Raspberry Pi is 5 Volt, I need to build up the relative low voltage power input of the solar panels (I guess they'd be around 1-2 Volt?).

To tackle this problem I build a little circuit, see below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMSNH.png]

If S1 and the middle switch are closed, Voltage will be build up by the inductor until 5 Volt is reached. Then a timer will automatically open the middle switch, causing current at 5V to flow to the capacitor, here current will be build up. As the capacitor is loaded with current S3 can be closed, powering the Pi.

I've got very basic knowledge on designing circuits, so my main question is: Will it work, or not? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: The most obvious way this can fail is that your solar panel must be able to deliver the required current. Ratings for a solar panel are always very optimistic about the lighting conditions, and mention open voltage and closed current, which the pannel will never deliver at the same time. Note that when you boost 1.5V to 5V you will need at least 3 times the 5V current, probably (much) more, and near 1V things might get much worse.

Comment: "voltage will be build up" No. Current will build up through the inductor. Voltage (across the inductor) will stay constant during that interval. That current built up at the inductor will be transferred to the capacitor once S2 opens, and the voltage at the capacitor will build up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [boost converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter), but you don't need neither S1 nor S3. And yes, it will work, but you need a controller IC to generate the proper PWM signal for S2, so that Vout is kept constant and at your desired level (the IC will measure that voltage, and will work in closed loop).

Your output voltage, assuming continuous mode, will be

$$
V_{out}=\frac{1}{1-D_2} V_{in},
$$

where D2 is the duty ratio of S2.

You can buy [something like this](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP1450-D.PDF), and add the external parts.

Comment: I think I've found a good controller: http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX1703.pdf what do you think?

Comment: @Rob It would work, too, but it is quite more expensive. The one I told you costs 0.84 GBP (http://uk.farnell.com/on-semiconductor/ncp1450asn50t1g/dc-dc-step-up-converter-5-0v-smd/dp/1460676RL), whereas I could only find yours for 9.24 EUR (http://www.digikey.es/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/2556570?k=MAX1703&stock=1).